# Is it possible to use the signalstats YAVG filter in FFMPEG to control the gamma correction in a video?

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg, terminal

I don't know if this is even possible, but something tells me it is… You see, I want to dynamically control the gamma correction in *FFMPEG/FFPLAY* depending on how bright/dark the frame being reproduced in a video/movie is…

For context, there's a filter in *FFMPEG/FFPLAY/FFPROBE* called `signalstats` that reports various useful sets of info about the video being processed/reproduced/analized. There's a `YAVG` parameter in the `signalstats` filter that returns the average `luma` level of the frame (https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#signalstats-1) . This is what I want to use to determine/calculate the `gamma` value to use in the eq filter `gamma` (https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#eq)… For example, in the end, I would like to use a formula like `"1-(YAVG/50)+1"`…

With the `signalstats YAVG` filter/parameter I've managed to do these unrelated exercises:

Analyze (with *FFPROBE*) a video and write a *log* file with the `YAVG` value for each frame:

```
ffprobe -f lavfi movie=VIDEO_INPUT,signalstats -show_entries frame_tags=lavfi.signalstats.YAVG -of csv="p=0" > YAVG.log
```

I have been able to also play a video (with *FFPLAY*) and show in the upper-left corner the `YAVG` values for each frame being reproduced:

First, we need to create a text file in the home folder called in this case "`signalstat_drawtext.txt`" with the following content:

```
    %{metadata:lavfi.signalstats.YAVG}
```

Then, we run this command:

```
    ffplay VIDEO_INPUT -vf signalstats,drawtext=fontfile=FreeSerif.ttf:fontcolor=lime:textfile=signalstat_drawtext.txt
```

However, I haven't been able to find/guess how to use the `YAVG` output to control (in realtime) the `gamma` value in the `eq` filter… I think it's possible, I just don't know how to write the command.

Using *FFPLAY*, I would imagine something like this:

```
ffplay VIDEO_INPUT -vf signalstats,eq=gamma="1-(metadata:lavfi.signalstats.YAVG/50)+1"
```

But of course, this doesn't work and I'm sure I'm just writing nonsense.